# How to changing width works in css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this page
http://cristianfertea.ro/blog-personal/

Right column passed as you can see below.

This is because this code

```
.theme-page-wrapper.right-layout .theme-content, 
.theme-page-wrapper.left-layout .theme-content {
    width: 90% !important; //This should be the 73%
}
```

I only want 70% value on this page and I tried this code

```
body.page.page-id-7674.theme-page-wrapper.right-layout .theme-content, 
.theme-page-wrapper.left-layout .theme-content {
    width: 73% !important;
}
```

Unfortunately this code is not working and can not understand why.
Can you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: By 'not working' you mean isn't applying that theme to your element on that page? How are you adding that CSS? You realise that the part after the comma is a separate selector - you probably don't need that (thought that shouldn't make a difference)? Can you come up with a simpler selector, or try removing the original one to make sure your new one does actually apply on its own? And ideally there'd be enough information in the question for people to answer without having to visit your blog, if you can see a way to add that into the question.

Comment: I see in your link i didn't found any of above css is applied in your page. There is lots of extra(unwanted) css is there which is messing just try top remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this style and try,

```
.theme-page-wrapper.right-layout .theme-content, .theme-page-wrapper.left-layout .theme-content {
  width: 73% !important;
}
```

Comment: I want this value only for the above page.
Not all pages

Comment: ok, over write with this  #mk-page-id-7674 .theme-content {
 width : 73% !important;
} at last line of css.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you are passing a page id reference only for the first rule only

```
body.page.page-id-7674.theme-page-wrapper.right-layout .theme-content, .theme-page-wrapper.left-layout .theme-content
{
    width:73% !important;
}
```

please try and pass the ref to all the rules as follows

```
 body.page.page-id-7674.theme-page-wrapper.right-layout .theme-content,
 body.page.page-id-7674.theme-page-wrapper.left-layout .theme-content
{
    width:73% !important;
}
```